# Bootstrap row in a row gives me a tiny white right margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap, it seems that nested rows gives me a small additionnal right margin like this:

[image]

by definition a row is :

```
margin-right : -15px;
margin-left : -15px;
```

my row are contained in a container-fluid to have the full window width.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this white space on the right ?

For instance :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="customize">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="display:flex; margin-top:50px;">
                <h2 class="slide-title">Personnalisez votre vitrine CINETIK</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the first row when i highlight it has the the exact size of the window and the second one has this margin on the right.
The first row is contained in a fluid container.

The white space has a fixed dimension, it is still the same size when a resize the window.

Comment: did you change the padding of .container-fluid or is it still at 15px left and right?

Comment: still 15px left & right !

Comment: and the highlighted row is direct child of .container-fluid?

Comment: can't give you my entire code, i edited a example of my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class=col-md-12 like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="customize">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="display:flex; margin-top:50px;">
            <h2 class="slide-title">Personnalisez votre vitrine CINETIK</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I used your solution with nopadding class, it imitates a row and seems to work ! Can you edit your answer and add that it also need the nopadding class : .nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
} thanks dude !

Answer (score 1):

use this code At css class

```
 *{margin:0;Padding:0}
```

Comment: i already done this: *{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
 box-sizing : border-box;
}